# How to create multiple instances of an "object" in Clojure?

Tags: oop, clojure

Which Clojure methods can I use to create multiple instances on an object and store then in an Java ArrayList?

I know how to do this in Java but I'm not sure how to proceed in Clojure, any help/pointers will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://clojure.org/java_interop

```
(doto (new java.util.ArrayList) 
    (.add (new Object)) 
    (.add (new Object)))
```

returns `#<ArrayList [java.lang.Object@5ae7fa2, java.lang.Object@33d6798]>`

There are 2 forms for creating new objects in clojure.

```
(Classname. args*)
(new Classname args*)
```

So here is the straightforward example how to create the java object in clojure. Firstly how it looks in Java:

```
Thread thread = new Thread("Hi there");
```

Clojure

```
; return instance of java.lang.Thread class
(new Thread "Hi there")
```

or another way

```
(Thread. "Hi there")
```

Comment: thanks I know how to work with arraylists but I dont know how to create an object and store them in an arraylist, if that makes sense

Comment: @RicardoSanchez The code in hsestupin's answer does create two objects and stores them in the array list.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez Sorry, i dont udnerstand what do u mean

Comment: Ok what I dont know how to do is to create an Object I would like to know how to do it in Clojure

Comment: @RicardoSanchez It's right there in the code: `(new Object)`. That's how you create an object.

Answer (score 0):

why not store in vector?

```
user=> (def lst (atom []))
user=> (swap! lst conj "String")
user=> (swap! lst conj 123)
user=> @lst
["String" 123]
```

Comment: So lst is like a C++ struct?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez No, lst is an atom containing a vector. An atom is (kinda, sorta) like a pointer in C++ and a vector is like a const vector in C++. So what this code does in C++ terms is: it creates a non-const pointer called `lst` pointing to a const empty vector. Then it creates a const vector containg the string `"String"` and makes `lst` point to that. Then it creates a const vector containing `"String"` and `123` and makes `lst` point to that. Then it dereferences the pointer. Note that this is not how you usually do things in Clojure.